# How to create a CoreData SUBQUERY with BETWEEN clause?

Tags: swift, core-data, subquery

I am attempting to retrieve only the Categories in which it's `entries.date` is between two dates. My research has pointed me that this is possible through a `SUBQUERY`. I followed the example in this medium.com article [SUBQUERY Is Not That Scary](https://medium.com/@Czajnikowski/subquery-is-not-that-scary-3f95cb9e2d98) however, when I run my project I get an `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "SUBQUERY(entries, $entry, $entry.date BETWEEN {%@, %@})"'`

I've uploaded an image of my datamodel and a code snippet of the contents of my `NSFetchedResultsController` where I construct my predicate statement with the `SUBQUERY`.

[Image of my data model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYTpL.png)

```
    // Create Fetch Request
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<CDCategory> = CDCategory.fetchRequest()

    // Configure Fetch Request
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "entriesCount", ascending: false)]
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(entries, $entry, $entry.date BETWEEN {%@, %@})", dataController.week.startDate as CVarArg, dataController.week.endDate as CVarArg)

    // Create Fetched Results Controller
    let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: CoreDataStack.instance.context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    // Configure Fetched Results Controller
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

    return fetchedResultsController
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a condition to the subquery: assuming you want to include `CDCategory` objects for which ANY of the `entries` has a date between your two given dates, you want the count of your subquery to be greater than zero:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(entries, $entry, $entry.date BETWEEN {%@, %@}).@count > 0", dataController.week.startDate as CVarArg, dataController.week.endDate as CVarArg)
```

Conversely, if you wanted to select only those where NONE of the entries' dates match, you want the count to be zero:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(entries, $entry, $entry.date BETWEEN {%@, %@}).@count == 0", dataController.week.startDate as CVarArg, dataController.week.endDate as CVarArg)
```

Similar constructions will allow you select only those where ALL the entries match your criteria.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful. I didn't think it was necessary to include the condition because I thought that the SUBQUERY already communicated which I would like to fetch.